# CSS colors not loaded and trouble making a div visible and invisible

Tags: javascript, html, css

I was taking a FreeCodeCamp project for JavaScript where I had to make a roman numerical converter, but unfortunately I have a couple issues:

1. Some CSS codes do not load such as margin colors and the background linear-gradient color.
2. The container that has the expected result that i want to make invisible at first and then invisible after the user input doesn't work as intended.

I think i made a big logical mistake but I just can't seem to find it.

Thank you for taking your time reviewing my code, English isn't my native language so I hope I made myself clear.

Here is all my code so far:

```js
const numberInput = document.getElementById("input");
const convertButton = document.getElementById("convert");
const output = document.getElementById("result");

const romanNumbers = [1000, 900, 500, 400, 100, 90, 50, 40, 10, 9, 5, 4, 1];
const romanLetters = ["M", "CM", "D", "CD", "C", "XC", "L", "XL", "X", "IX", "V", "IV", "I"];

function convertToRoman(number) {

  if (number === 0) {
    output.textContent = "Roman numerals do not represent zero.";
    return;
  }

  if (isNaN(number) || number < 1 || number > 3999) {
    const errorMessage = number < 1 ? "Please enter a number greater than or equal to 1." :
      number > 3999 ? "Please enter a number less than or equal to 3999." :
      "Please enter a valid number.";
    output.textContent = errorMessage;
    return;
  }

  let roman = "";
  for (let i = 0; i < romanNumbers.length; i++) {
    while (number >= romanNumbers[i]) {
      roman += romanLetters[i];
      number -= romanNumbers[i];
    }
  }
  output.textContent = roman;
  output.parentElement.style.visibility = "visible";
}

convertButton.addEventListener("click", function(event) {
  event.preventDefault(); // Prevent form submission (optional)
  const enteredNumber = parseInt(numberInput.value);
  convertToRoman(enteredNumber);
  // Clear previous output on new conversion (optional):
  // output.textContent = ""; // Uncomment if you prefer to clear the output
});
```

```css
html {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
}

body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  font-family: Rubik, Robot, open sans, sans-serif;
  background-color: linear-gradient(to top right, #00AAFF, #00FF6C);
}

.container {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
  margin: 10px solid black;
  padding: 10px;
  border-radius: 10px;
}

#numberForm {
  flex-direction: row;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: space-between;
}

.hidden {
  visibility: invisible;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <h1>Roman Numeral Converter</h1>
  <h3>Made by Yazzine</h3>
</div>

<div class="container">
  <form id="numberForm">
    <p>Enter a number between 1 and 3999:</p>
    <div>
      <input type="number" id="input" placeholder="Your number">
      <button type="submit" id="convert">Convert</button>
    </div>
  </form>
</div>

<div class="container hidden" id="result-container">
  <p>Roman Numeral: <span id="result"></span></p>
</div>
```

Comment: Gradients aren't background *colors* they are treated as background *images* and margins don't have colors.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first problem, the `div` containing the output being visible on page load, is because `invisible` isn't a valid setting for `visibility`. You should use `hidden` instead.

The other issue, with the linear gradient not being shown on the `body`, is because `linear-gradient()` needs to be set on the `background`, not the `background-color`.

Finally, you cannot set a colour on a `margin`, only a width. I would presume you want to set a `border-color` instead.

With those issues corrected, your code works fine:

```js
const numberInput = document.getElementById("input");
const convertButton = document.getElementById("convert");
const output = document.getElementById("result");

const romanNumbers = [1000, 900, 500, 400, 100, 90, 50, 40, 10, 9, 5, 4, 1];
const romanLetters = ["M", "CM", "D", "CD", "C", "XC", "L", "XL", "X", "IX", "V", "IV", "I"];

function convertToRoman(number) {
  if (number === 0) {
    output.textContent = "Roman numerals do not represent zero.";
    return;
  }

  if (isNaN(number) || number < 1 || number > 3999) {
    const errorMessage = number < 1 ? "Please enter a number greater than or equal to 1." :
      number > 3999 ? "Please enter a number less than or equal to 3999." :
      "Please enter a valid number.";
    output.textContent = errorMessage;
    return;
  }

  let roman = "";
  for (let i = 0; i < romanNumbers.length; i++) {
    while (number >= romanNumbers[i]) {
      roman += romanLetters[i];
      number -= romanNumbers[i];
    }
  }
  output.textContent = roman;
  output.parentElement.style.visibility = "visible";
}

convertButton.addEventListener("click", function(event) {
  event.preventDefault(); // Prevent form submission (optional)
  const enteredNumber = parseInt(numberInput.value);
  convertToRoman(enteredNumber);
  // Clear previous output on new conversion (optional):
  // output.textContent = ""; // Uncomment if you prefer to clear the output
});
```

```css
html {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
}

body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  font-family: Rubik, Robot, open sans, sans-serif;
  background: linear-gradient(to top right, #00AAFF, #00FF6C);
}

.container {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
  margin: 10px;
  padding: 10px;
  border-radius: 10px;
}

#numberForm {
  flex-direction: row;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: space-between;
}

.hidden {
  visibility: hidden;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <h1>Roman Numeral Converter</h1>
  <h3>Made by Yazzine</h3>
</div>

<div class="container">
  <form id="numberForm">
    <p>Enter a number between 1 and 3999:</p>
    <div>
      <input type="number" id="input" placeholder="Your number">
      <button type="submit" id="convert">Convert</button>
    </div>
  </form>
</div>

<div class="container hidden" id="result-container">
  <p>Roman Numeral: <span id="result"></span></p>
</div>
```

Note for future reference, if you ever encounter anything you're not sure about regarding CSS, [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS) is the best reference resource. It will provide full documentation for all properties as well as examples of usage.